# Multiple new lines in batch?

Tags: batch-file, output, paragraph

```
@echo off
Set /A number=1 & goto loop

:loop

echo= line %number% > output.txt
:: #So here is where I'd like to make a new paragraph to continue my loop
Set /A number= %number% + 1
if %number% EQU 21 exit

goto loop
```

So output.txt now is line 20.

What I need here is 
line 1
line 2
line 3
and so on until 20

Answer (score 3):

A single line in a batch file:

```bat
@(For /L %%A In (1,1,20) Do @Echo(line %%A)>output.txt
```

A single line in the Command Prompt

```bat
(For /L %A In (1,1,20) Do @Echo(line %A)>output.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

When you make > to file it creates new file. If you need to add to file use >>.
So you can make

```
echo= start > output.txt
```

before loop and

```
echo= line %number% >> output.txt
```

inside loop

Comment: To initialize a new file you'd better use i.e. `Type Nul >outout.txt`

Comment: I agree, this way more suited